# How to update total price in cart listview in android

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` which displays items in my shopping cart from my existing database and at the bottom i have created `TextView` of total price of all the items in my cart,but the total price that displays at the bottom does not get updated according to the products in my cart.I am not getting where am I making mistake,please help me out.

xml code for `TextView` of Total price:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalItemPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="RS "
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

**AddToCartFragment.java :**

```
private ArrayList<GenieCart_List_Model> mAddList;

private void getCart_Data() {
    try {
            db = new DataBasehelper1(getActivity());
            mAddList = new ArrayList<GenieCart_List_Model>();
            mAddList = db.getAllCotacts();
            long sum = db.sum_Of_Rs();
            mTotalItemPrice.setText("Total Rs : " + sum);
            db.close();
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

**DataBaseHelper1.java:**

```
public long sum_Of_Rs() {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" select * from  " +CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + CONTACTS_PRODUCT_ID + " DESC " , null);
    ArrayList<GenieCart_List_Model> list = new ArrayList<GenieCart_List_Model>();
    try {

        res.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < res.getCount(); i++) {

            GenieCart_List_Model Prod_Details = new GenieCart_List_Model();
            Prod_Details.setPrice(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_PRODUCT_RS)));
            Prod_Details.setProdID(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_PRODUCT_ID)));

            try {
                int total = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_PRODUCT_RS)));

                Sum = Sum + total;
                return Sum;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            list.add(Prod_Details);
            res.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Sum;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? 
How does your code behave if you debug it?

Comment: have you get long value after debugging..

Comment: i debugged and found that In database inserting is done properly but while fetching the price of individual products  from database is not happening ,is it possible if we take price of products from adapter (used to set individual product detail in row of listview) )and do sum method  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a conversion issue.

**Set Text like that**

**mTotalItemPrice.setText("Total Rs : " + String.valueOf(sum));**

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest to change your SQL Query to :

```
      public long sum_Of_Rs() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM ( " +CONTACTS_PRODUCT_RS + ") FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME , null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        return i;
}
```

PS: SUM() will return a number in the same format of the column that you are reading. if CONTACTS_PRODUCT_RS is a float/double use

```
 float i = c.getFloat(0);
 double i = c.getDouble(0);
```

Hope it help !! :))

Comment: can you share the exception so i try to help ?

Comment: I am getting null value in sum,the problem is in fetching price value of each item in cart

Comment: i missed some "  in my query i modified the query . i think thats why you get null value .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line " return sum; " from try catch .

Comment: Can you please tell me if  I remove this line then how should I call sum variable in  AddToCartFragment.java to set Total Rs

Comment: I debugged and found that the problem is in fetching price value from database, the sum value from  sum_of_Rs is null

Answer (score 0):

Your method `sum_Of_Rs()` is right. To update the total cost call your method `sum_Of_Rs()` and set the result to the TextView every time you add or delete an item in the cart i.e. if you are using ListView always do these steps when you notify the listview about the data changes using `notifyDataSetChanged()` you can also improve your method **sum_Of_Rs()** by changing your method to the following:

```
public long sum_Of_Rs() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM (" + CONTACTS_PRODUCT_RS + ") FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME , null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int sum = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return sum;
}
```